# Dimensional Vector spoace with injective surjective and bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, injective-module

I know there are similar questions on the internet, but I'm not getting it smart.
i hope u can help me,

Let $B,C$ finite dimensional Vector space with $\dim(C) = \dim(B)$ and $R \in Hom(B,C)$. 
Then it should be equivalent to R is injective, R is surjective and R is bijective.

I hope u can help me to construct a proof

Comment: I have no idea what  you're trying to say/ask.

Comment: I want to construct a proof, R is injective and that's equivalent with R is surjective

Comment: That's obviously not so - $R$ might not be injective. I really doubt that "R is injective and that's equivalent with R is surjective" is what you were asked to prove! Surely you were asked to prove that R is injective if and only if R is surjective. That's not the same as what you said! $p\land(p\iff q)$ is not the same as $p\iff q$. You should  state what you're asked to prove, exactly as it was given to you, without reworig anything...

Comment: sorry my mistake i changed it now

Comment: Still makes no sense. "it should be equivalent to R is injective, R is surjective" (i) raises the question of _what_ should be equivalent, (ii) does _not_ say R is injective if is equivalent to R is surjective.  IF you actually want to prove that R is injective if and only if R is surjective you should say "R is injective if and only if R is surjective".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David has mentioned, it would help if you made the question clearer. Since the statement does not hold for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, is it possible that you actually want to prove it for finite-dimensional vector spaces?

If that is the case, choose a basis for $B$; say, $\lbrace x_1,\dots ,x_n\rbrace$. If $R$ is injective, try showing that $\lbrace R(x_1),\dots ,R(x_n)\rbrace$ is linearly independent in $C$. Here you must use (a) that $R$ is injective and (b) that $R$ is linear. Then conclude from dimension considerations that $\mathrm{span} (R(x_1),\dots ,R(x_n))$ is a basis for $C$, hence showing that $R$ is surjective.

The proof of surjective $\Rightarrow$ injective is somewhat similar.

**Walkthrough.** In case you give up, here is a walkthrough of the proof for injective $\Rightarrow$ surjective. Let $\lbrace x_1,\dots ,x_n\rbrace$ be as above. Then $\mathrm{dim} (B) = \mathrm{dim} (C) = n$. We will show that $\lbrace R(x_1),\dots ,R(x_n)\rbrace$ is a basis for $C$.

First we must see that $R(x_1),\dots ,R(x_n)$ are linearly independent. Suppose we have
$$
\alpha_1R(x_1)+\dots +\alpha_n R(x_n) = 0.
$$
But $R$ is linear, so we get:
$$
R(\alpha_1x_1 + \dots + \alpha_nx_n) = 0.
$$
Since $R$ is injective, we then have
$$
\alpha_1x_1 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n = 0.
$$
But $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ are linearly independent, so we must have $\alpha_i = 0$ for each $i=1,\dots ,n$. This shows that $R(x_1),\dots ,R(x_n)$ are linearly independent. Hence they must span an $n$-dimensional subspace of $C$. Since $C$ is $n$-dimensional, this must be all of $C$. But then $R$ is surjective.

Comment: I was hoping to redirect him towards something more fruitful. That's why I wrote "is it possible that you actually want to prove it for finite-dimensional vector spaces?". I think it's likely that he's misread what he has to prove.

Comment: yeah thank you, i was indeed misreading

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This is a reply to the original version of the question, where it was specified that $B$ and $C$ were "endless dimensional". So of course it's irrelevant to the current version, where $B$ and $C$ are finite-dimensional. May as well leave it here, to show that the hypothesis is needed.

The question is totally unclear, and the comment doesn't clarify things much. It seems *possible* that you actually want to prove that $R$ is injective if and only if $R$ is surjective. If so:

(i) you should say so!

(ii) you can't prove that because it's false. Say $B$ is the space of sequences of real numbers. Let $C=B$, and define $R:B\to C$ by $$Rx=(0,x_1,x_2,\dots).$$
Then $R$ is injective  but not surjective.

You should give a similar example of a linear map which is surjective but not injective.